# Aggregate First Grouped Item from Subsequent Items

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have user game sessions containing: user id, game id, score and a timestamp when the game was played.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

sc = SparkContext("local")

sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ("u1", "g1", 10, 0),
    ("u1", "g3", 2, 2),
    ("u1", "g3", 5, 3),
    ("u1", "g4", 5, 4),
    ("u2", "g2", 1, 1),
], ["UserID", "GameID", "Score", "Time"])
```

**Desired Output**

```
+------+-------------+-------------+
|UserID|MaxScoreGame1|MaxScoreGame2|
+------+-------------+-------------+
|    u1|           10|            5|
|    u2|            1|         null|
+------+-------------+-------------+
```

I want to transform the data such that I get the max score of the first game the user played as well as the max score of the second game (bonus if I can also get the max score of all subsequent games). Unfortunately I'm not sure how that's possible to do with Spark SQL.

I know I can group by UserID, GameID and then agg to get the max score and min time. Not sure to how to proceed from there.

Clarification: note that MaxScoreGame1 and MaxScoreGame2 refer to the first and second game user player; not the GameID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a combination of Window functions and Pivot.

1. Get the row number for every game partitioned by UserID ordered by Time.
2. Filter down to GameNumber being 1 or 2.
3. Pivot on that to get your desired output shape.

Unfortunately I am using scala not python, but the below should be fairly easily transferable to python library.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

// Use a window function to get row number
val rowNumberWindow = Window.partitionBy(col("UserId")).orderBy(col("Time"))  

val output = {
  df
    .select(
      col("*"),
      row_number().over(rowNumberWindow).alias("GameNumber")
    )
    .filter(col("GameNumber") <= lit(2))
    .groupBy(col("UserId"))
    .pivot("GameNumber")
    .agg(
      sum(col("Score"))
    )
}

output.show()

+------+---+----+
|UserId|  1|   2|
+------+---+----+
|    u1| 10|   2|
|    u2|  1|null|
+------+---+----+
```

Comment: Also to add if you want to see more than two games in the output just don't filter and the pivot will take care of the rest.

Comment: Window and row_number did the trick. I'm going to post my solution in PySpark which is a bit different. Can you verify your code works with a show so I can award you the answer?

Comment: Just updated with output and also noticed I had actually used select instead of groupBy on the pivot, which wouldn't work. Interested in how you got 5 as the 2nd game score for user 1, assuming there is a typo in the original data frame, as according to your post ("u1", "g3", 2, 2), ("u1", "g3", 5, 3),

Answer (score 1):

Solution with PySpark:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window

rowNumberWindow = Window.partitionBy("UserID").orderBy(F.col("Time"))

(df
 .groupBy("UserID", "GameID")
 .agg(F.max("Score").alias("Score"),
      F.min("Time").alias("Time"))
 .select(F.col("*"),
         F.row_number().over(rowNumberWindow).alias("GameNumber"))
 .filter(F.col("GameNumber") <= F.lit(2))
 .withColumn("GameMaxScoreCol", F.concat(F.lit("MaxScoreGame"), F.col("GameNumber")))
 .groupBy("UserID")
 .pivot("GameMaxScoreCol")  
 .agg(F.max("Score"))
).show()

+------+-------------+-------------+
|UserID|MaxScoreGame1|MaxScoreGame2|
+------+-------------+-------------+
|    u1|           10|            5|
|    u2|            1|         null|
+------+-------------+-------------+
```